# Checkbox in angularjs 1.3

Tags: angularjs

I tried the following code on angularjs 1.3.0 (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js):-

```
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkboxmodel" ng-checked="true" ng-true-value="Blue" ng-false-value="Red"></input> {{chkboxmodel}}
```

However, when i click on the checkbox, {{chkboxmodel}} does not return either Blue or Red.

however when I change Angularjs version to 1.2.0 I get Red or Blue.

any idea what i need to do?

Comment: Probably does not make a different but the input tag does not have a end tag. <input type="checkbox" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo below
remove `ng-checked="true"` from your input

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.chkboxmodel = "Blue";

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkboxmodel" ng-true-value="Blue" ng-false-value="Red" />{{chkboxmodel}}
  </div>
</div>
```